# extJS 4.0.2 select row by simulating mouse click event from chrome console

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, google-chrome-console

I want to select row by simulating mouse click or firingEvent mouse click from Chrome console, unfortunately, all previous attempts were unsuccesfully and don't work.

`document.getElementById('#....').click()` and etc..

Afterwards, I found that I need to rewrite/use fire event handling from ext-all.js (4.0.2a), but didn't figure it out how to implement this explicitly in my case.
Could you please assist?

Thank you in advance.

Illustration of the desired state

[image]

Comment: Means do u want to select manually ?

Comment: Well, I want to insert JS into Chrome console and see the desired state, so when I run custom JS the first row should become selected and "Assign" button should become active.

Comment: can you explain why you want to insert into chrome console.?

Comment: well if I will be able to make selection via chrome console then I will be able to insert the same piece of code into the Chrome extension which will inject when I want it.

Comment: So you can use `grid.getSelectionModel().select(grid.getStore().getAt(0));` and on select event you can enable the your button.

Comment: excuse me, but this code doesn't work :(
when I am typing "grid" inside Chrome console I get the following option:
gridDataModelassignedTokensGrid
so, I've tried to use :

grid.getSelectionModel().select(gridDataModelassignedTokensGrid.getStore().getAt(0));
but recieve: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: grid is not defined

gridDataModelassignedTokensGrid.getSelectionModel().select(gridDataModelassignedTokensGrid.getStore().getAt(0));
Uncaught TypeError: gridDataModelassignedTokensGrid.getSelectionModel is not a function

Comment: First you need to get the your grid component then it will work

Comment: is it possible to point me what I am doing wrong? tried to different variants:
var grid = Ext.getDom('gridview-1050') 
var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridview-1050')
but it seems to me that I am selecting not grid but a DOM element. So, how to find the grid component on the page? cause I can view only divs and tables which have got mentioned above id (gridview-1050)

Comment: instead of this `Ext.getDom('gridview-1050')` you need to use `Ext.getCmp('gridview-1050')`. you can refer my **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2f5a)**

Comment: Super!!! Thank you very much Jadhav! :)

Comment: Hearty welcome @Marat Gainutdinov. I have added answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [`grid.getSelectionModel()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-getSelectionModel) and inside of `Ext.selection.Model` have method [select()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-select);

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2f5a)**, I have created a demo using your code. I hope this will help/guide you.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'gridStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                'name': 'Lisa',
                "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                "phone": "555-111-1224"
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

            title: 'Grid manually selection',

            store: 'gridStore',

            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            bbar: [{
                text: 'Assign',
                itemId: 'assignBtn',
                disabled: true// See initially button is disabled I have enable when record has been selected.
            }],

            listeners: {

                afterrender: function () {
                    this.getSelectionModel().select(this.getStore().getAt(0));
                },

                select: function (grid, rec, index) {
                    this.down('#assignBtn').setDisabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe someone will find this useful, the exact code which I used inside Chrome Console:

var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridview-1050'); // assign Grid component  to our variable
grid.getSelectionModel().select(grid.getStore().getAt(0)); // select first row within our Grid component
document.getElementById('ext-gen1401').click()  // now "Assing" button become active so we can use click() method